# Ratio of maximal to minimal jump in the set of angle multiples

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle in the complex plain. Let $d:S^1\times S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ be the distance function given by the arc length. Let $\theta\in S^1$ be an element of infinite order, that is $\theta^n\neq 1$ for any $n\neq 0$. I would like to know what is the behavior of the ratio 
\begin{equation}
a_N=\frac{\max_{1\leq n\leq N} d(1,\theta^n)}{\min_{1\leq n\leq N} d(1,\theta^n)}
\end{equation}
when $N$ goes to $\infty$. I would like it to be bounded above and below, but any information would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having $\theta$ of infinite order is equivalent to $\theta\not\in 2\pi\Bbb Q$. As a consequence, $\{\theta^n\}_{n}$ is [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) on $S^1$, implying in particular that the image is [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation). This, in turn, means that $\max_{1\leq n\leq N}d(1,\theta^n)\to\pi$ and $\min_{1\leq n\leq N}d(1,\theta^n)\to 0$, so the desired limit diverges to infinity.

It is increasing, however, so $\alpha_1=1$ bounds the sequence from below.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I am afraid I mixed things up, and did not formulate correctly the question I in fact wanted to ask. I have corrected the statement here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655841/ratio-of-maximal-to-minimal-jump-in-the-set-of-angle-multiples-corrected