# Ratio of maximal to minimal jump in the set of angle multiples (corrected)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

(This is the corrected version of the question I asked here: [Ratio of maximal to minimal jump in the set of angle multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655725/ratio-of-maximal-to-minimal-jump-in-the-set-of-angle-multiples).)

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle in the complex plain. Let $d:S^1\times S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ be the distance function given by the arc length. Let $\theta\in S^1$ be an element of infinite order, that is $\theta^n\neq 1$ for any $n\neq 0$. 
Define $J_N$ to be the set of those pairs $(i,j)$, such that $1\leq i,j\leq N$ and the smaller open arc between $\theta^i$ and $\theta^j$ does not contain any other $\theta^k$, $1\leq k\leq N$.

I would like to know what is the behavior of the ratio 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\max_{(i,j)\in J_N} d(\theta^i,\theta^j)}{\min_{(i,j)\in J_N}d(\theta^i,\theta^j)}
\end{equation}

when $N$ goes to $\infty$. I would like it to be bounded above and below, but any information would be useful.

Comment: The [proof](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_45_03%2FS1446788700031062a.pdf&code=19ede453ad149601533e435a6523a1b7) of the Three Gap Theorem might provide some ideas.